# Prove the following fact (Probability)

Tags: probability

I'm trying to prove the following fact

> $$P[A\cup B] \ge P[A]$$
>   This is what I've done so far, but I got stuck 
>   $$P[A \cup B] \ge P[A]$$
>   $$P[A] + P[B] - P[A \cap B] \ge P[A]$$
>   $$P[A \cap B] + P[A \setminus B] + P[B] - P[A \cap B] \ge P[A]$$
>   $$P[A \setminus B] + P[B] \ge P[A]$$
>   How can I proceed after this? please help?

Comment: You took a wrong path.  Aim for $\mathsf P(A)+\mathsf P(B\setminus A)\geq \mathsf P(A)$ in the last step.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\;A\cap B\subseteq B\;$ we get $\;P(A\cap B)\le P(B)\;$ and thus $\;P(B)-P(A\cap B)\ge 0\;$ , so
$$P(A\cup B)=P(A)+\overbrace{P(B)-P(A\cap B)}^{\ge0}\ge P(A)$$

Comment: If you're going to use monotonicity, why not just say $A\le A\cup B$ in the first place?

Comment: @TedShifrin Because, apparently, the OP tried that. But, of course, you're right.

Answer (score 0):

Your work looks pretty close, but some tweaking is required.

The point of expressing $A\cup B$ into a union of set differences is that they are *disjoint*, and the probability of a union of disjoint events is the sum of the probabilities of the events.   (IE: The intersection of disjoint events has zero probability measure.)

This leaves you with a sum of probabilities (all addition, no subtractions), and all probabilities are never less than zero.   So the sum must be never less than just one of the terms alone.

$$Y\geqslant 0 \implies X+Y\geqslant X$$

Since you want to prove the probability is never less than $\mathsf P(A)$, then use $A\cup B= A\cup(B\setminus A)$.

---

> $$\begin{align} \mathsf P(A\cup B) ~=~& \mathsf P\big(A\cup (B\setminus A)\big) \\[1ex] ~=~ & \mathsf P(A)+\mathsf P(B\setminus A) & \text{union of disjoint events} \\[2ex]\therefore~\mathsf P(A\cup B) ~\geq ~ & \mathsf P(A) &\because~ \mathsf P(B\setminus A) \geq 0 \end{align}$$